# Adding comments to YAML produced with PyYaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm creating Yaml documents from my own python objects using PyYaml. 
for example my object:

```
class MyObj(object):
    name = "boby"
    age = 34
```

becomes:

```
boby:
   age: 34
```

So far so good.

But I have not found a way to programmatically add comments to the produced yaml so it will look like:

```
boby:       # this is the name
   age: 34  # in years
```

Looking at PyYaml documentation and also at the code, I found no way of doing so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm almost certain there is no way to do this with PyYAML short of essentially rewriting major parts of the library, and making a number of decisions about how to handle comments. Would you want comments added by the representer (eg, per-class)? Or per-instance somehow (even harder)? This is somewhat unfortunate, as the ability to add comments could be somewhat useful.

Comment: Thanks @cge. Preserving comments would be very helpful when processing yaml documents programatically.

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/pyyaml-comment-emitter seems to understand how to do it using the Event/Dumper interfaces. Not posting as an answer yet because I haven't verified it to work yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save/dump a YAML file with comments in PyYAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml)

Comment: Can you include the representer for a MyObj instance? Because if you just yaml.dump(MyObj()), you won't get that output. My [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) library allows adding comments on collection types, and so with that representer I probably could give you a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have some representer for the MyObj class, as by default dumping  ( `print(yaml.dump(MyObj()))` ) with PyYAML will give you:

```
!!python/object:__main__.MyObj {}
```

PyYAML can only do one thing with the comments in your desired output: discard them. If you would read that desired output back in, you end
up with a dict containing a dict (`{'boby': {'age': 34}}`, you would not get a `MyObj()` instance because there is no tag information)

The enhanced version for PyYAML that I developed ([ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)) can read in YAML with comments, preserve the comments and write comments when dumping.
If you read your desired output, the resulting data will look (and act) like a dict containing a dict, but in reality there is more complex data structure that can handle the comments. You can however create that structure when ruamel.yaml asks you to dump an instance of `MyObj` and if you add the comments at that time, you will get your desired output.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap


class MyObj():
    name = "boby"
    age = 34

    def convert_to_yaml_struct(self):
        x = CommentedMap()
        a = CommentedMap()
        x[data.name] = a
        x.yaml_add_eol_comment('this is the name', 'boby', 11)
        a['age'] = data.age
        a.yaml_add_eol_comment('in years', 'age', 11)
        return x

    @staticmethod
    def yaml_representer(dumper, data, flow_style=False):
        assert isinstance(dumper, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
        return dumper.represent_dict(data.convert_to_yaml_struct())


ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper.add_representer(MyObj, MyObj.yaml_representer)

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(MyObj(), sys.stdout)
```

Which prints:

```
boby:      # this is the name
  age: 34  # in years
```

There is no need to wait with creating the `CommentedMap` instances until you want to represent the `MyObj` instance. I would e.g. make `name` and `age` into properties that get/set values from/on the approprate `CommentedMap`. That way you could more easily add the comments before the `yaml_representer` static method is called to represent the `MyObj` instance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution I came up with; it's a bit complex but less complex than ruamel, as it works entirely with the plain PyYAML API, and does not *round trip* comments (so it would not be an appropriate answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml)).  It's probably not as robust overall yet, as I have not tested extensively, but it seems good-enough for my use case, which is that I want dicts/mappings to be able to have comments, both for the entire mapping, as well as per-item comments.

I believe that round-tripping comments--in this limited context--would also be possible with a similar approach, but I have not tried it, as it's not currently a use-case I have.

Finally, while this solution does not implement adding per-item comment to items in lists/sequences (as this is not something I need at the moment) it could easily be extended to do so.

First, as in ruamel, we need a sort of `CommentedMapping` class, which associates comments with each key in a [Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping).  There are many possible approaches to this; mine is just one:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping, MutableMapping

class CommentedMapping(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, d, comment=None, comments={}):
        self.mapping = d
        self.comment = comment
        self.comments = comments

    def get_comment(self, *path):
        if not path:
            return self.comment

        # Look the key up in self (recursively) and raise a
        # KeyError or other execption if such a key does not
        # exist in the nested structure
        sub = self.mapping
        for p in path:
            if isinstance(sub, CommentedMapping):
                # Subvert comment copying
                sub = sub.mapping[p]
            else:
                sub = sub[p]

        comment = None
        if len(path) == 1:
            comment = self.comments.get(path[0])
        if comment is None:
            comment = self.comments.get(path)
        return comment

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        val = self.mapping[item]
        if (isinstance(val, (dict, Mapping)) and
                not isinstance(val, CommentedMapping)):
            comment = self.get_comment(item)
            comments = {k[1:]: v for k, v in self.comments.items()
                        if isinstance(k, tuple) and len(k) > 1 and k[0] == item}
            val = self.__class__(val, comment=comment, comments=comments)
        return val

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.mapping[item] = value

    def __delitem__(self, item):
        del self.mapping[item]
        for k in list(self.comments):
            if k == item or (isinstance(k, tuple) and k and k[0] == item):
                del self.comments[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.mapping)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mapping)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.mapping}, comment={self.comment!r}, comments={self.comments})'
```

This class has both a `.comment` attribute, so that it can carry an overall comment for the mapping, and a `.comments` attribute containing per-key comments.  It also allows adding comments for keys in nested dicts, by specifying the key path as a tuple.  E.g. `comments={('c', 'd'): 'comment'}` allows specifying a comment for the key `'d'` in the nested dict at `'c'`.  When getting items from `CommentedMapping`, if the item's value is a dict/Mapping, it is also wrapped in a `CommentedMapping` in such a way that preserves its comments.  This is useful for recursive calls into the YAML representer for nested structures.

Next we need to implement a custom YAML [Dumper](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/dumper.py#L45) which takes care of the full process of serializing an object to YAML.  A Dumper is a complicated class that's composed from four other classes, an [`Emitter`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/emitter.py#L31), a [`Serializer`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/serializer.py#L11), a [`Representer`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/representer.py#L272), and a [`Resolver`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/resolver.py#L167).  Of these we only have to implement the first three; `Resolver`s are more concerned with, e.g. how implict scalars like `1` get resolved to the correct type, as well as determining the default tags for various values.  It's not really involved here.

First we implement a *resolver*.  The resolver is responsible for recognizing different Python types, and mapping them to their appropriate *nodes* in the native YAML data structure/representation graph.  Namely, these include scalar nodes, sequence nodes, and mapping nodes.  For example, the base `Representer` class includes a representer for Python `dict`s which converts them to a `MappingNode` (each item in the dict in turn consists of a pair of `ScalarNode`s, one for each key and one for each value).

In order to attach comments to entire mappings, as well as to each key in a mapping, we introduce two new `Node` types which are not formally part of the YAML specification:

```py
from yaml.node import Node, ScalarNode, MappingNode

class CommentedNode(Node):
    """Dummy base class for all nodes with attached comments."""


class CommentedScalarNode(ScalarNode, CommentedNode):
    def __init__(self, tag, value, start_mark=None, end_mark=None, style=None,
                 comment=None):
        super().__init__(tag, value, start_mark, end_mark, style)
        self.comment = comment


class CommentedMappingNode(MappingNode, CommentedNode):
    def __init__(self, tag, value, start_mark=None, end_mark=None,
                 flow_style=None, comment=None, comments={}):
        super().__init__(tag, value, start_mark, end_mark, flow_style)
        self.comment = comment
        self.comments = comments
```

We then add a `CommentedRepresenter` which includes code for representing a `CommentedMapping` as a `CommentedMappingNode`.  In fact, it just reuses the base class's code for representing a mapping, but converts the returned `MappingNode` to a `CommentedMappingNode`.  It also converts each key from a `ScalarNode` to a `CommentedscalarNode`.  We base it on `SafeRepresenter` here since I don't need serialization of arbitrary Python objects:

```py
from yaml.representer import SafeRepresenter

class CommentedRepresenter(SafeRepresenter):
    def represent_commented_mapping(self, data):
        node = super().represent_dict(data)
        comments = {k: data.get_comment(k) for k in data}
        value = []
        for k, v in node.value:
            if k.value in comments:
                k = CommentedScalarNode(
                        k.tag, k.value,
                        k.start_mark, k.end_mark, k.style,
                        comment=comments[k.value])
            value.append((k, v))

        node = CommentedMappingNode(
            node.tag,
            value,
            flow_style=False,  # commented dicts must be in block style
                               # this could be implemented differently for flow-style
                               # maps, but for my case I only want block-style, and
                               # it makes things much simpler
            comment=data.get_comment(),
            comments=comments
        )
        return node

    yaml_representers = SafeRepresenter.yaml_representers.copy()
    yaml_representers[CommentedMapping] = represent_commented_mapping
```

Next we need to implement a subclass of `Serializer`.  The *serializer* is responsible for walking the representation graph of nodes, and for each node output one or more events to the *emitter*, which is a complicated (and sometimes difficult to follow) state machine, which receives a stream of events and outputs the appropriate YAML markup for each event (e.g. there is a `MappingStartEvent` which, when received, will output a `{` if it's a flow-style mapping, and/or add the appropriate level of indentation for subsequent output up to the corresponding `MappingEndEvent`.

Point being, the new serializer must output events representing comments, so that the emitter can know when it needs to emit a comment.  This is handling simply by adding a `CommentEvent` and emitting them every time a `CommentedMappingNode` or `CommentedScalarNode` are encountered in the representation:

```py
from yaml import Event

class CommentEvent(yaml.Event):
    """
    Simple stream event representing a comment to be output to the stream.
    """
    def __init__(self, value, start_mark=None, end_mark=None):
        super().__init__(start_mark, end_mark)
        self.value = value

class CommentedSerializer(Serializer):
    def serialize_node(self, node, parent, index):
        if (node not in self.serialized_nodes and
                isinstance(node, CommentedNode) and
                not (isinstance(node, CommentedMappingNode) and
                     isinstance(parent, CommentedMappingNode))):
            # Emit CommentEvents, but only if the current node is not a
            # CommentedMappingNode nested in another CommentedMappingNode (in
            # which case we would have already emitted its comment via the
            # parent mapping)
            self.emit(CommentEvent(node.comment))

        super().serialize_node(node, parent, index)
```

Next, the `Emitter` needs to be subclassed to handle `CommentEvent`s.  This is perhaps the trickiest part, since as I wrote the emitter is a bit complex and fragile, and written in such a way that it's difficult to modify the state machine (I am tempted to rewrite it more clearly, but don't have time right now).  So I experimented with a number of different solutions.

The key method here is [`Emitter.emit`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/emitter.py#L111) which processes the event stream, and calls "state" methods which perform some action depending on what state the machine is in, which is in turn affected by what events appear in the stream.  An important realization is that the stream processing is suspended in many cases while waiting for more events to come in--this is what the [`Emitter.need_more_events`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/emitter.py#L120) method is responsible for.  In some cases, before the current event can be handled, more events need to come in first.  For example, in the case of `MappingStartEvent` at least 3 more events need to be buffered on the stream: the first key/value pair, and the possible the next key.  The Emitter needs to know, before it can begin formatting a map, if there are one or more items in the map, and possibly also the length of the first key/value pair.  The number of events required before the current event can be handled are hard-coded in the `need_more_events` method.

The problem is that this does not account for the now possible presence of `CommentEvent`s on the event stream, which should not impact processing of other events.  Therefore the [`Emitter.need_events`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/2f463cf5b0e98a52bc20e348d1e69761bf263b86/lib3/yaml/emitter.py#L133) method to account for the presence of `CommentEvent`s.  E.g. if the current event is `MappingStartEvent`, and there are 3 subsequent events buffered, if one of those are a `CommentEvent` we can't count it, so we'll need at a minimum 4 events (in case the next one is one of the expected events in a mapping).

Finally, every time a `CommentEvent` is encountered on the stream, we forcibly break out of the current event processing loop to handle writing the comment, then pop the `CommentEvent` off the stream and continue as if nothing happened.  This is the end result:

```py
import textwrap
from yaml.emitter import Emitter

class CommentedEmitter(Emitter):
    def need_more_events(self):
        if self.events and isinstance(self.events[0], CommentEvent):
            # If the next event is a comment, always break out of the event
            # handling loop so that we divert it for comment handling
            return True
        return super().need_more_events()

    def need_events(self, count):
        # Hack-y: the minimal number of queued events needed to start
        # a block-level event is hard-coded, and does not account for
        # possible comment events, so here we increase the necessary
        # count for every comment event
        comments = [e for e in self.events if isinstance(e, CommentEvent)]
        return super().need_events(count + min(count, len(comments)))

    def emit(self, event):
        if self.events and isinstance(self.events[0], CommentEvent):
            # Write the comment, then pop it off the event stream and continue
            # as normal
            self.write_comment(self.events[0].value)
            self.events.pop(0)

        super().emit(event)

    def write_comment(self, comment):
        indent = self.indent or 0
        width = self.best_width - indent - 2  # 2 for the comment prefix '# '
        lines = ['# ' + line for line in wrap(comment, width)]

        for line in lines:
            if self.encoding:
                line = line.encode(self.encoding)
            self.write_indent()
            self.stream.write(line)
            self.write_line_break()
```

I also experimented with different approaches to the implementation of `write_comment`.  The `Emitter` base class has its own method (`write_plain`) which can handle writing text to the stream with appropriate indentation and line-wrapping.  However, it's not quite flexible enough to handle something like comments, where each line needs to be prefixed with something like `'# '`.  One technique I tried was monkey-patching the `write_indent` method to handle this case, but in the end it was too ugly.  I found that simply using Python's built-in `textwrap.wrap` was sufficient for my case.

Next, we create the dumper by subclassing the existing `SafeDumper` but inserting our new classes into the MRO:

```py
from yaml import SafeDumper

class CommentedDumper(CommentedEmitter, CommentedSerializer,
                      CommentedRepresenter, SafeDumper):
    """
    Extension of `yaml.SafeDumper` that supports writing `CommentedMapping`s with
    all comments output as YAML comments.
    """
```

Here's an example usage:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> d = CommentedMapping({
...     'a': 1,
...     'b': 2,
...     'c': {'d': 3},
... }, comment='my commented dict', comments={
...     'a': 'a comment',
...     'b': 'b comment',
...     'c': 'long string ' * 44,
...     ('c', 'd'): 'd comment'
... })
>>> print(yaml.dump(d, Dumper=CommentedDumper))
# my commented dict
# a comment
a: 1
# b comment
b: 2
# long string long string long string long string long string long string long
# string long string long string long string long string long string long string
# long string long string long string long string long string long string long
# string long string long string long string long string long string long string
# long string long string long string long string long string long string long
# string long string long string long string long string long string long string
# long string long string long string long string long string
c:
  # d comment
  d: 3
```

I still haven't tested this solution very extensively, and it likely still contains bugs.  I'll update it as I use it more and find corner-cases, etc.

Comment: This answer deserves its own github.

Comment: @Jonathan Haha, thanks.  It's actually implemented in a real project.  But I might separate it out to its own package.  I just haven't done it yet because `ruamel` already exists and also does this IIUC.

Comment: This seems more complex than ruamel

Comment: @avibrazil To implement or to use?  Because obviously just using ruamel which already has this feature is easier.  That's not the point...