# How to read a component in YAML file so that I can edit it's key value using ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

This is my YAML file (`input.yaml`):

```
team_member:
  name: Max
  hobbies:
    - Reading

team_leader:
  name: Stuart
  hobbies:
    - dancing
```

I want to edit this YAML file to add more values in key 'hobbies', example:

```
team_member:
  name: Max
  hobbies:
    - Reading
    - Painting

team_leader:
  name: Stuart
  hobbies:
    - Dancing
    - Fishing
```

I tried to implement the code [Anthon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767944) to fit my situation but it didn't helped at all, because the indention level of that YAML file is different from mine.
Example:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
for elem in data:
    if elem['name'] == 'Stuart':
         elem['hobbies'] = ['Fishing']
         break  # no need to iterate further
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

I get error "TypeError('string indices must be integers',)", I know this code might be completely wrong, but I am new to ruamel.yaml.

How to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing missing form the error message displayed is the line number (I assume that it is 9). That points to the line

```
    if elem['name'] == 'Stuart':
```

And if that doesn't give you a clue, the approach that I recommend in such cases is starting to add some `print` functions, so that you know what you are working on. The `for` loop looks like:

```
for elem in data:
    print('elem', elem)
    if elem['name'] == 'Stuart':
         print('elem->hobbies', elem['hobbies'])
         elem['hobbies'] = ['Fishing']
```

this prints

```
 elem team_member
```

before the exception is thrown, and I hope that will make you realize your are not iterating over the *elem*ents (items) of a list, but over the *key*s of a dict (constructed from the root level mapping in your YAML). And the *value* associated with the key is the object having a key `name` and a key `hobbies`.

So change the variable `elem` to `key` to make clear what you're handling and then proceed to work with `value`, the value associated with that key instead of `elem` within that loop¹:

```
for key in data:
    value = data[key]
    if value['name'] == 'Stuart':
         print('value->hobbies', value['hobbies'])
         value['hobbies'] = ['Fishing']
```

This gives:

```
value->hobbies ['dancing']
team_member:
  name: Max
  hobbies:
  - Reading

team_leader:
  name: Stuart
  hobbies:
  - Fishing
```

So we got rid of the exception, but the result is not exactly what you want. The element `dancing` for the key 'hobbies' is gone, because you assign a new (list) value to that key, whereas what you should do is append a single item to the list. We can also get rid of the print function by now:

```
for key in data:
    value = data[key]
    if value['name'] == 'Stuart':
         value['hobbies'].append('Fishing')
```

This will get you two items in the final sequence in the file. There is a few more things to address:

- the capitalization of `dancing` incorrect. To correct that, add a line handling the list if there is only one element
- the code for the name `Max`, needs to be added (and that is why you need to get rid of the `break` in your code)
- the empty line, is considered a comment on the last element of the first sequence, that comment needs to be moved
- your indentation of sequences is non-default

The final code would be like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

path = Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)  # for the non-default indentation of sequences

data = yaml.load(path)
for key in data:
    value = data[key]
    if value['name'] == 'Stuart':
         if len(value['hobbies']) == 1:
             value['hobbies'][0] = value['hobbies'][0].capitalize()
         value['hobbies'].append('Fishing')
    elif value['name'] == 'Max':
         last_item_index = len(value['hobbies']) - 1
         value['hobbies'].append('Painting')
         comments = value['hobbies'].ca
         if not comments.items[last_item_index][0].value.strip():
             # move empty comment lines from previous last item to new last item
             comments.items[last_item_index + 1] = comments.items.pop(last_item_index)

yaml.dump(data, path)
```

Which gives something quite close to what you wanted to get

```
team_member:
  name: Max
  hobbies:
    - Reading
    - Painting

team_leader:
  name: Stuart
  hobbies:
    - Dancing
    - Fishing
```

---

¹<sub>Alternative for the first two lines: `for key, value in data.items()`</sub>

Comment: Thanks Anthon, I tried your code and it gets executed completely but my yaml file is not getting edited. I have also tried adding these line in code:

    out = Path('output.yaml')
    out = sys.stdout
    yaml.dump(data, out)

Comment: Actually, I am using Visual Studio to run this code, the python console window shows the output as you showed above but the actual yaml file does not gets edited. I want to edit the same input.yaml file but just for testing I added out = Path('output.yaml') | out = sys.stdout | yaml.dump(data, out) , but didn't helped.

Comment: There is no indication in your question that you want to write the original file., what you added doesn't work because the first assignment to out gets nullified by doing `out = sys.stdout`. If you leave that part out things of course work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anthon your code worked I have to edit this code as follows:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
path = Path('input.yaml')
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)  # for the non-default indentation of sequences
with open(path) as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
for key in data:
    value = data[key]
    if value['name'] == 'Stuart':
         if len(value['hobbies']) == 1:
             value['hobbies'][0] = value['hobbies'][0].capitalize()
         value['hobbies'].append('Fishing')
    elif value['name'] == 'Max':
         last_item_index = len(value['hobbies']) - 1
         value['hobbies'].append('Painting')
         comments = value['hobbies'].ca
         if not comments.items[last_item_index][0].value.strip():
             # move empty comment lines from previous last item to new last item
             comments.items[last_item_index + 1] = comments.items.pop(last_item_index)
yaml.dump(data, path)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that you want to dump the output back to `input.yaml`, and updated to use `Path`. Using `open(path)` is not good Python, use `path.open()` instead (or pass `path` in directly to load as I do). You are importing `sys` in your code, but are not using it.