# How to prevent earlier list values from getting deleted in the edited yaml file?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

This is my YAML file (`data.yaml`):

```
  - Department: "IT"
    name: "abcd"
    Education: "Bachlore of Engineering"
```

And I want to edit it as follows:

```
  - Department: "IT"
    name: "abcd"
    Education: "Bachlore of Engineering"
  - Department: "Production"
    name: "xyz"
    Education: "Bachlore of Engineering"
  - Department: "Management"
    name: "ab"
    Education: "MBA"
```

This is my code (currently adding only second list):

---

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString, DoubleQuotedScalarString

datapath= Path('C:/Users/Master 1TB/source/repos/check2/check2/data.yaml')

with YAML(output=datapath) as yaml:
  yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
  code = yaml.load(datapath)
  code = [{
           "Department": "Production"
           "name": "xyz"
           "Education": "Bachlore of Engineering"
          }]
  yaml.dump(code)
```

---

Now the problem when code dump the new list in the `data.yaml` the earlier list gets deleted, hence my output is:

```
  - Department: "Production"
    name: "xyz"
    Education: "Bachlore of Engineering"
```

Instead I want the previous item also in the output and as you explained in the link ([How to read a component in YAML file so that I can edit it's key value using ruamel.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899662/how-to-read-a-component-in-yaml-file-so-that-i-can-edit-its-key-value-using-rua#) ), I have to append the new list value, but this is possible only if I have one list value.
What can be done in this scenario?
Also I am going to add more list values in `data.yaml` (preserving all the earlier list in the same YAML file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sequence at the root level of your `data.yaml` file, and when you load that you
get a list in your variable code. After that you assigne to `code` and what you need to do
is `append` an item to that list, or `extend` that list with a list of one or more items.

The other thing you cannot really do is have the same file for reading
and writing when you use the `output` parameter to the with statement. Either write to a different file
or load from the file then dump the updated structure to the same file.

You should also make sure you have commas between the key-value pairs, as it is now your code will not run.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString, DoubleQuotedScalarString

datapath = Path('data.yaml')

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(datapath)
code.extend([{
             "Department": "Production",
             "name": "xyz",
             "Education": "Bachlore of Engineering",
             }])

yaml.dump(code, datapath)
print(datapath.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
- Department: IT
  name: abcd
  Education: Bachlore of Engineering
- Department: Production
  name: xyz
  Education: Bachlore of Engineering
```