# Read a file and edit the file at the same time (line by line) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Suppose I have a file `temp.yaml`.

```
# Comment shouldn't be deleted
passwords:
    key1: __password__
    key2: __password__
    key3: __password2__
    key4: __password__
# All comments should be preserved
passwords-new:
    key1: __newPassword__
```

In this file, I want to have each `__password__` field with a different value. Essentially, all of the passwords in this file would have a different value.

I was thinking to read the file line by line and store/replace a password with a newly generated password. But not sure, how I can go through the file line by line and edit that particular line at the same time in bash.

Any other solution or better approach would also work.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain why it wasn't satisfactory.

Comment: The general idea is that you don't "edit" lines as such. You read in a line from one file and write out to another.

Comment: For now, I have used sed separately for searching 'key1: __password__' and replacing it with 'key1: xysdxy`. But in future, if we want to add a new key, we want to handle it automatically and do not want someone to have edit new sed statements for new keys.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use bash instead of something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml

Comment: Almost our entire code base is in bash for that product. So we are looking for the simplest and easiest way to do it in bash.

Answer (score 0):

If the YAML file isn't too big, you could use Bash code to make the edits in memory and write the results back to the file.  This, [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean, code demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# Set passwords in a YAML file.  Update the file in place.
function set_yaml_passwords
{
    local -r yaml_file=$1

    # Create a regular expression to match key/password lines
    local -r key_rx='^([[:space:]]*key[[:digit:]]*:[[:space:]]*)'
    local -r pw_rx='__[[:alnum:]]*[Pp]assword[[:alnum:]]*__[[:space:]]*$'
    local -r key_pw_rx=${key_rx}${pw_rx}

    # Read the YAML file lines into an array, setting passwords as we go
    local yaml_lines=() is_updated=0
    local line keystring newpw
    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]] ; do
        if [[ $line =~ $key_pw_rx ]] ; then
            keystring=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            newpw=$(pwgen 10)
            yaml_lines+=( "${keystring}${newpw}" )
            is_updated=1
        else
            yaml_lines+=( "$line" )
        fi
    done <"$yaml_file"

    # If any passwords have been set, update the YAML file
    if (( is_updated )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "${yaml_lines[@]}" >"$yaml_file"
        printf "Updated '%s'\\n" "$yaml_file" >&2
    fi

    return 0
}

set_yaml_passwords 'temp.yaml'
```

This is an example of a YAML file produced by running the code above on the example YAML file given in the question:

```
# Comment shouldn't be deleted
passwords:
    key1: yai9cegiD4
    key2: Ahtah1eyoh
    key3: ya1teo1ooB
    key4: AhGae5EiLe
# All comments should be preserved
passwords-new:
    key1: oaKoh0teiK
```

- Line-by-line processing in Bash code is very slow.  The code above took almost 1 second to process a ten thousand line file (with a small number of key/password lines) on my (oldish) Linux system.  On a modern system you'll run into time problems long before you run into memory problems.
- I used `pwgen 10` to generate new passwords.  You may want to do something else.
- There's no error checking in the demonstration code.  Real code should check for missing file, unreadable file, unwritable file, wrong number of arguments to the function, etc.