# Idea for new python lib - yamldict

Tags: python, yaml

I very often use yaml as storage for configuration. Until I have only read yaml I can in yaml file have comments and my formating (for exanoke extra newlines).
The problem appears when I want to change one parameter and save it.
Example of the problem:

```
yaml1="""
A:
  B:
    C:1
# comment

D: 2

E: 3
"""
from yaml import load, dump
dump(load(yaml1)) != yaml1
```

Do you think the library which works in this way will be usable by a bigger audience and it is worth do start that project:

```
yaml1="""
A:
  B:
    C:1
# comment

D: 2

E: 3
"""
from dictyaml import DictYaml()
dy = DictYaml(yaml1)
dy["A"]["B"]["C"] = 2
str(dy) == """
A:
  B:
    C:2
# comment

D: 2

E: 3
"""
```

Comment: It exists. See ruamel.yaml Also dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml

Comment: Thanks, ruamel is just I am looking for.